# How to turn this into a "list of lists" in R

Tags: r

I want to change the format from the following output:

```
v1 <- c("Friday", "Wednesday")
v2 <- c("Sunday", "Monday", "Sunday", "Friday")
mylist <- list(v1, v2)
```

to something like:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Friday"
[2] "Wednesday"
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: that is exactly what you have

Comment: It's not. The output is [[1]] [1] "Friday" "Wednesday"

Comment: yes that output is exactly what it means. The like the `Wednesday` is the second. you can subset it. ie try `mylist[[1]][1]` to obtain `Friday` and `mylist[[1]][2]` to obtain `Wednesday`

Comment: @akrun the output is not a list of lists. it is a list of vectors

Comment: @Onyambu I would request you to refer to the `title` of the post

Comment: @LathanLiou  Your title says `list of lists`.  So in that case, the vector elements should be convert to `list` of 1 element each

Answer (score 1):

If we want a `list` of `lists`

```
list(as.list(v1), as.list(v2))
```

---

Or from the `list` 'mylist'

```
lapply(mylist, as.list)
```